# SQL Inner Join respect order of primary table (DBF files DBASE IV)

Tags: sql, vb.net, inner-join, dbf

I'm integrating a solution with a point of sale software. I'm almost done just need to get the ordering/sequence correct.

I'm working in VB.net.

This is my query:

```
 SELECT B.DESCRIPT AS description,
 B.REF_NO AS upc,
 A.QUANTY AS quantity,
 ROUND((A.PRICE_PAID * (1+(C.TAX_PCT/100))),2) AS unit_price,
 A.DEL_CODE AS discount_percent
 FROM (TABLE.DBF A INNER JOIN MENU.DBF B ON B.REF_NO = A.REF_NO),
 TAXTBL.DBF C
 WHERE C.TAX_DESC='TAX'
```

And it yields a result something like this:
(sequence is an auto-incrementing column set to the datatable)
[image]

The results from the query are being ordered by the upc/REF_NO, due to the inner join between TABLE.DBF and MENU.DBF. When I take out the MENU.DBF components, I get the correct order from TABLE.DBF.

I need to make this query respect the order from TABLE.DBF. The items should be ordered as such:
[image]
(time_sent doesnt help because (1) its a batch of items and (2) multiple items can be added even within the same second)

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about dbf, but in almost all SQL I have run into the order is an implementation detail, so you should not rely on it and should provide your own order.

That would mean using an [`ORDER BY xyz`](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/order_by.php) at the end of your query

Comment: Yeah. Ideally we would order by the primary key. But the tables we are working with have no primary key :/ . Rather awkward. The only options are to sort by REF_NO/upc or price. But neither of those will mimic the required order... The only thing that has the order is the raw DBF file.

Comment: Again, that is an implementation detail, so I am not sure that you can get around it other than creating an id that you can order by. You could pump out the original table and store it in a temp table and use auto-generated id's maybe? That is pretty ugly but should work